# Get list of properties from List of objects

Tags: c#

Currently I use `foreach` loop to return a list of `object` properties.

```
 class X
 {
     List<X> Z = GetXlist();
     List<String> r = new List<String>();

     foreach (var z in Z)
     {
         r.Add(z.A);
     }

     return r;
}
```

Is there a way that I can shorten this so that I don't have to write the `foreach` loop?

Comment: You're not writing a for loop.  There is a difference that you should be aware of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178218/for-vs-foreach-vs-linq

Answer (score 252, accepted):

**[LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx)** is the answer. You can use it to "project" from your object collection to another collection - in this case a collection of object property values.

```
List<string> properties = objectList.Select(o => o.StringProperty).ToList();
```

Comment: If you want a *distinct* list of the property values, it is a bit longer, but still awesome: 
`List<string> properties = objectList.GroupBy(o => o.StringProperty).Select(g=>g.First().StringProperty).ToList();`

Answer (score 15):

You could use LINQ:

```
List<X> Z = GetXlist();

List<String> r = Z.Select(z => z.A).ToList();

return r;
```

Or just,

```
return GetXlist().Select(z => z.A).ToList();
```

Find out more about **[LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)**. It is *pretty* useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
List<string> properties = objectList.Select(o => o.StringProperty).ToList();
```

You Also Can Do By Private `OverLoading` Method and Use That in LINQ Query.

Comment: This does not provide value to the established answer

Answer (score -1):

You can get working [example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AsFCj7).
Here is what will simplify your implement by using Linq.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class X
{
    public List<string> GetExplicitProperties()
    {
        List<X> z = GetXlist();
        List<string> r = z.Select(s => s.A).ToList();

        return r;
    }
}
```